# Sort Grants by expiration date

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an app where users have projects and projects get matched with grants.  Originally I set up the app so that admin set a delivery date when creating a match.  Matches were displayed by delivery period.

Now I want to switch it so that grants are listed by their expiration date (expires_at on the grant model).  I can list the `project.matches` but I cant seem to access the expiration date of the grant.  So `matches.first.grant.expires_at` gets the expiration date of the first grant but how do I do this in code for all the grant matches?

The match.rb:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :grant
  belongs_to :project
...
  def self.delivery_date_before(date)
    where("delivery_date  < ? ", date)
  end

  def self.delivery_date_after(date)
    where("delivery_date  >= ? ", date)
  end

  def self.delivery_date_between(from, to)
    where("delivery_date  >= ? and delivery_date <= ?", from, to)
  end

  def match_uniqueness
    if grant_id_changed? || project_id_changed?
      if grant_id.present? && project_id.present? && Match.exists?(grant_id: grant_id, project_id: project_id)
        errors.add :project_id, "already assigned this grant"
      end
    end
  end

  def deadline
    grant.expires_at
  end

  def expired?
    if deadline.present?
      deadline < Time.zone.now
    else
      false
    end
  end
...
end
```

The project.rb:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :matches

  def previous_matches
    range = user.current_period_range
    matches.delivery_date_before(range[0])
  end

  def current_matches
    range = user.current_period_range
    matches.delivery_date_between(range[0], range[1])
  end

  def future_matches
    range = user.future_period_range
    matches.delivery_date_after(range[0])
  end

  def to_s
    project_title
  end
end
```

The user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :matches, through: :projects
...
  def current_period_range
    today = Time.zone.now
      [ DateTime.new(today.year, today.month, today.day), DateTime.new(today.year, (today.month + 2), today.day) ]
  end

  def future_period_range
    today = Time.zone.now
      [ DateTime.new(today.year, (today.month + 2), today.day), DateTime.new(today.year, (today.month + 6), today.day) ]
  end
end
```

One instance of the match listing from the researcher dashboard.  I have two others like this for previous and future matches.

```
<% if @project.matches.any? %>
    <h3><%= project_title @project %></h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 dashboard-panel ">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading"><h4>Your grant matches
                        <span class='small'><%= period_in_words %></span>
                    </h4></div>
                    <% if @project.current_matches.any? %>
                        <%= render 'match_table', matches: @project.current_matches %>
                    <% else %>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" >
                                <div class='well'>
                                    No matches for this period
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And finally the match table:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Grant</th>
    <th>Deadline</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Matching notes</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <% matches.each do |match| %>
    <tr>
      <td class="match_col"><%= match.grant.name %></td>
      <td class="match_col">
        <%= deadline_in_words match %></td>
      <td class="match_col"><%= match.submission_status %></td>
      <td><%= match.notes.html_safe %></td>
      <td class="match_col center">
        <% if match.submission_active? %>
          <%= link_to "Continue", edit_grant_app_type_submission_path(match.grant, match.app_type, match.submission), class:"btn btn-info"%>
        <% else %>
          <%= link_to 'Apply', match.grant, class:"btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

I know I need to update the `self.delivery_date...` methods but I'm not sure what to change it to.  Switching it to deadline doesn't work because its looking for a field on the match table.  I feel like I should be able to say `@project.matches.grant.expires_at`  or like  `@project.matches.grant.each.expires_at`.  Or possibly change the self.deivery_date to something like:

```
def self.delivery_date_before(date)
 Grant.where("expires_at  < ? ", date)
end
```

or

```
def self.delivery_date_before(date)
 includes.(:grant).where("expires_at  < ? ", date)
end
```

Thanks for looking!

UPDATE:

I tried

```
def self.expires_before(date)
  includes(:grants).where(:grants => :expires_at >= Date.today)
end
```

but now I'm getting "comparison of Symbol with Date failed" this feels like the closest I've gotten but I don't know why expires_at is coming up as a symbol because it is a datetime field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to try do something like this

```
def self.expires_date_before(date)
  where(:grant_id => Grant.where("expires_at <= ?", date))
end
```